# Need to replace the title of main array (bigger count) with sub array (lesser count) when the label shows a specific value on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have 2 Title Arrays with 2 different sizes as follows.

```
Ar Pro Title Array: ["brioche burger bun x4", "White hot dog rolls x6 420g", "sliced energy bread", "High protein bagel 120g", "La Boulangere croissants x6 240g", "Mountain wholewheat wraps 200g", "chocolate chip cookies", "Milk Sliced Bread 360g", "Europastry glazed donuts 52g", "high fibre white bread 700g"]

Cp Pro Title Array: [" honey cake large", "Schar Pan Blanco 250g", "Chocolate slice 100g", "fresh boneless chicken thighs 500g"]
```

The Ar Pro Title Array is the main array that displays the title label of my cell and there is a product availability label in red and green as "Cancelled", "Unavailable" and "Substituted".
Then there is a label called availabaleStatus.text displays static string (not from any API calls) in the cell as per some logics see the code below.

```
var availabilityStatus = ""
            let chosenProductUpc = subRanges.chosenProductUpc ?? ""
            let cancelledItems = subRanges.substitutelineCancelled ?? false
            if chosenProductUpc != "" {
               header.substatusTextstyleGreen()
               availabilityStatus = "Substituted"
               header.unavailableLabel.text = "Substituted"
               header.selectBtn.isHidden = true
               header.bottomPanel.isHidden = false
               header.timerLabel.isHidden = true
        
            } else if cancelledItems == true {
               header.substatusTextstyleRed()
               availabilityStatus = "Cancelled"
               header.unavailableLabel.text = "Cancelled"
               header.selectBtn.isHidden = true
               header.bottomPanel.isHidden = false
               header.bpThumb.isHidden = true
               header.timerLabel.isHidden = true
               header.bpTitleLabel.text = "Don't Substitute this item"
            }
            else {
               header.substatusTextstyleRed()
                availabilityStatus = "Unavailable"
               header.unavailableLabel.text = "Unavailable"
               header.selectBtn.isHidden = false
               header.bottomPanel.isHidden = true
               header.timerLabel.isHidden = false
              
              
            }
```

check the screen shot here [image]

What I want is I need to replace Ar Pro Title array only when availability Status shows as "Substituted" otherwise just simply display as "Don't Substitute" for the header.unavailableLabel.text

Comment: Isn't that a matter of adding some simple `if`-`else` logic?  I don't really understand what the issue is here.

Comment: Issue is about index out of range ..

Comment: Please explain in more detail in your post.